# Automatically adding @ImplicitParams with specific type of method argument of Spring Controller

Tags: spring, swagger-2.0, springfox

Previously, I had Spring controller as below.

```
@RequestMapping(method = GET)
public List<TheResponse> getResponses(
    @RequestParam(defaultValue = "1") int offset, 
    @RequestParam(defaultValue = "10") int limit) {

    Pagination pagination = new Pagination(offset, limit);
    ...
    return someResponse;
}
```

Swagger was generating document of this method with correct parameters information.

Later I created `PaginationArgResolver` by implementing `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`. After that, I have to update the method as below, and apply `@ApiImplicitParams` to make it work with Swagger.

```
@ApiImplicitParams({ 
    @ApiImplicitParam(name = "offset", dataType = "int", defaultValue = "1"),
    @ApiImplicitParam(name = "limit", dataType = "int", defaultValue = "10")
})
@RequestMapping(method = GET)
public List<TheResponse> getResponses(@ApiIgnore Pagination pagination) {

    ...
}
```

**Is there anyway `@ImplicitParams` is applied automatically whenever `Pagination` type argument is found?**

OR

**If I expose `@PaginationSupported` annotation, can I process it to achieve same results?**

I am currently using springfox v2.4.0.

PS. I can edit source of `Pagination` class, in case some swagger annotation is needed there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why adding `@ApiIgnore` springfox will resolve these attributes inside the class automatically. When you want to add default values and other stuff you can add the `@ApiParam` annotation to the class attributes as well.

```
class Pagination {
    @ApiParam(defaultValue = "1")
    private int offset;
    // [..]
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I have tried it. By the way, I am currently using SpringFox version 2.4.0. I have also update the question mentioning this version.

Comment: I tried to upgrade to 2.6.0 and even 2.6.1, and got exception mention in [this issue](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1538). It doesn't throw exception on 2.5.0 but doesn't resolve the problem either.

Comment: to test your solution, I skipped the exception by selecting specific API. I tested it with springfox v2.6.1 and **it worked**. Thanks.